# how to get the checked position of listview and send it to another class

Tags: android, xml, listview

I want to get the checked position and sent it to another class to use it here is the code

selection.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

```
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                            boolean isChecked) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (isChecked) {
                            Toast.makeText(MissionsListAdapter.this.context,
                                    "You checked item" + ipostion, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



                        } else {

                        }
                    }
```

I wand send the iposition to another class I tried many ways and i got an errors

Answer (score 1):

Try this (creating a new listView and associate it with the existed one then use the function getPositionForView to get your checked position)

```
ListView lv = getListView();
int position = lv.getPositionForView(v);
```

goodLuck();

Answer (score 1):

An **interface** can simply solve your problem.

Use of interface is holding reference of your interface implemented class.

1. Create an interface with a method.
2. Implement it on the class which you are intented to get the position and override the method to get call back.
3. Pass the class reference as parameter to the listview.
4. Invoke the interface method using the listener class reference when you need to pass positio.